# Which table does each row belong to in a view?

Tags: mysql

If you create a view from a union of multiple tables can you find out which table each row came from, or would you need to do something like:

`SELECT set-table-name-string-here as table_name`

for each bit of the union?

Comment: `SELECT ... , 'table1' AS source FROM ... UNION ALL SELECT ... , 'table2' FROM ...`

Comment: Do the tables have unique keys, e.g. GUIDs?

Comment: You question is unclear, can you add some info to show an example of what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Note that views in MySQL are fantastically useless